# Refresh page after click button search, to search again laravel ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have search button, when i searching for first time, it works. But for second time it doesn't.
Example i search for A - success- then i search B, its not failed, but more on it doesn't work. So i need to refresh my page every time i search a keyword. Here is my code snip. I make it short.

```
$("#btn_search").click(function() {
  var key = $("#keyword").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/filter',
    method: "GET",
    data: {"KeyName":key},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(resx) {
      if (resx) {
        $("#tb_result").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        for (resx of data) {
          var url = '<tr><td>HI<td></tr>';
          $('#tb_result').append(html);
```

Comment: What's up with that success function...? What is `html`? Why are you trying to display HI instead of `resx`? How does any of that "work"?

Comment: Can you `console.log(resx)` at the beginning of `success`?

Comment: @ChrisG no, actually in html i show the result, i only HI instead just to make it short. Because my code is too long, and only for counting.

Comment: @MiniPlat, Check that your button is working on second time. put console.log() to check event is fire or not

Comment: To find the error we need to see the actual code. The code in your question is completely broken and pretty much useless to solve this.